# C++ / Convert windows-1250 to utf-8?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, cpu-word, polish

I have string from my POCO lib,

```
const vector <ReadMails::Mail>& mails = rm.downloadLastMails(10);

string getContentFromMail = "";
for (const auto& m : mails) {
    if (m.getContentType.find("text") != string::npos) {
        getContentFromMail = m.content;
    }
    else {
        getContentFromMail = "<Nie udało się odczytać>";
    }

    string time = ctime(&m.receivedTime);
    string dataEmail = to_string(m.mailId) + " | \"" + m.subject + "\" (" + m.sender + ") [" + to_string(m.sizeInBytes) + "B] Content: " + getContentFromMail;
    cout << dataEmail << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
10 | "Test" (Test test<test@test.com>) [2863B] Content: ─ů┼Ť─ç┼é├│
9 | "Test" (Test test<test@test.com>) [2880B] Content: Testowa wiadomo┼Ť─ç
8 | "Wielkie mi─Ö┼Ťnie mimo zamkni─Ötych si┼éowni? To mo┼╝liwe! Sprawd┼║ >>" ("Musculinex - EML /o2" <o2@o2.pl>) [45192B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
7 | "Szukasz solidnego ubezpieczyciela OC/AC?  Znajd┼║ go z centrum pomocy por├│wneo" ("Porowneo.pl /o2" <o2@o2.pl>) [26637B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
6 | "Zadbaj o odporno┼Ť─ç z Omega-3 ÔÇôWypr├│buj za darmo!" ("Natural Pharmaceuticals Sp. z o.o. /o2" <o2@o2.pl>) [13960B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
5 | "Szukasz solidnego ubezpieczyciela OC/AC?  Znajd┼║ go z centrum pomocy por├│wneo" ("Porowneo.pl /o2" <o2@o2.pl>) [35373B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
4 | "NORMALNIE LATO 2021! Z rabatami do 800 z┼é! Sprawd┼║ >>" ("Rainbow /o2" <no-response@o2.pl>) [150081B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
3 | "Test" (Test test<test@test.com>) [2745B] Content: Test
2 | "W┼é─ůcz protok├│┼é IMAP/POP/SMTP" (Poczta o2 <poczta@o2.pl>) [16066B] Content: <Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>
```

As you can see, this string has strange characters like: ─ů┼Ť─ç┼é├│

But the content looks like:
─ů┼Ť─ç┼é├│ (In real it is: ąśćłó)
Testowa wiadomo┼Ť─ç (In real it is: Testowa wiadomość)

So now i have the question how i can convert the line content to utf-8 content with polish words in c++?

Comment: C++ has very limited support for converting text between charsets. You will have to look at the email's `Content-Type` header(s) to determine which charset(s) are actually being used, and then you should use a Unicode library, such as ICU or libcurl, to handle the actual conversion to UTF-8, if the text is not already in UTF-8 (which yours is clearly not).

Comment: Code `getContentFromMail = "<Nie udało się odczytać>";` does not match the output `<Nie uda│o siŕ odczytaŠ>`. You should start by checking the encoding of the source files, and the compiler settings for source and execution character sets.